# What should I upload for submitting a proprietary app to USC?

Tags: software-center, application-development, packaging

I have an app ready to be submitted to Ubuntu Software Center.
It is open-source and the [source code is in Github](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness). But I want to submit it under proprietary license ($0.0 however) as I would not have to package it then.
There will be link to the source code in the about menu of the app though.

I want to know if I can just upload the source code or would I have to make .dsc .changes, .orig.tar.gz etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload source code or compiled binary to software center . But it will take lot of time to appear in the software center. If you want to release your app quickly, create a debian source package and upload it

Comment: What do you mean by lot of time? Could you specify the amount of time in weeks or months?